# Why does this snippet not work in VS 2013?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
#include <memory>

class Foo {
};

class Bar {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_;
};

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    Bar bar2 = std::move(bar);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
1>c:\users\szx\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\main.cpp(13): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Bar::Bar(const Bar &)'
```

But GCC is able to compile it without errors: http://ideone.com/CiDcGI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is valid. VS2013 rejects it because that compiler doesn't implement implicit generation of move constructor and move assignment operator. Note that you're not even allowed to explicitly default them. Your only option is to implement the move constructor.

```
class Bar {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_;
public:
    Bar(Bar&& b) : foo_(std::move(b.foo_)) {}
    Bar() = default;
};
```

From MSDN: [Support For C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

> "Rvalue references v3.0" adds new rules to automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions. However, this is not implemented in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013, due to time and resource constraints.

Comment: Just as an additional info: this is fixed (modulo bugs) in November 2013's CTP, which is not an official release anyway.